# Any way jenkins to auto build by polling to Github without hooking?

Tags: jenkins, github, build

I want jenkins to build when the Github gets merged to a master branch. There's a way using hooking, but I can not use my url for jenkins. It is not exposed to public.

Is there any way jenkins to build by polling to Gitbut without hooking its url?

Comment: Have you tried adding your GitHub credentials to Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your own Jenkins instance, you can still use your Jenkins URL in your GitHub webhook setting by making one, with [**ngrok**](https://ngrok.com/) (which has a free offer)

If not, you would need to switch to a polling approach, where a cron job in Jenkins would every x minutes monitor your GitHub master branch and trgiger a job on new commits

[image: http://lh3.ggpht.com/-_t31sX5XYBU/VQXVt6PucQI/AAAAAAAABt0/gjCgub_9nH0/jenkins009_thumb%25255B1%25255D.png?imgmax=800]

Comment: I am waiting for other answers. Because it says SCM could cause burden on server.